# Почему возникает ошибка со стрелочными функциями в webpack 4?

Tags: javascript, babel

Настраиваю webpack и всплывает ошибка

```
ERROR in ./es6/scripts.js 23:8
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (23:8)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|     }
| 
>     tick=()=>{
|         this.time--;
|         this.render();</code
```

мой .babelrc

```
{
    "presets": [
        "@babel/preset-env"
    ],
    "plugins": [
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"
    ]
}
```

мой webpack.config.js

```
let path = require('path');

let conf = {
    entry: './es6/scripts.js',
    output:{
            path: path.resolve(__dirname,'./js'),
            filename: 'main.js',
            publicPath: 'js/'
    },
    devServer: {
        overlay:true
    },
    module: {
        rules:[
            {
                test:'/\.js$/',
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                //exlude 'node_modules'    
            }
        ]
    }
};

module.exports = conf;
```

мой package.json

```
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server --mode development --open",
    "build": "webpack --mode production"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.4.4",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.4.4",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.4.4",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.5",
    "webpack": "^4.31.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.3.1"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй в конфиге babel (.babelrc включить пресет react:
https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-react/

```js
{
  "presets": ["react"]
}
```